# justify text around of image using bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have content box using bootstrap 3.

CSS:

```
.news-thumbs{
   margin:10px;
}
```

HTML:

```
   <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-6">
            <article class="feature">
                <figure class="pull-left news-thumbs thumbnail">
                    <img alt="" src="img/noor.png"><img alt="" src="http://1.gravatar.com/avatar/3a4fe156e7e23a3f6c023ab0abb305e2?s=160&amp;d=http%3A%2F%2Fcss-tricks.com%2Fimages%2Fget-gravatar.png%3Fs%3D160&amp;r=PG" class="avatar avatar-160 photo" height="160" width="160">
                </figure>
                <h1>

                    H1 Title

                </h1>
                <p class="justify">

                   Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description
                  …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …
                   …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …
                   …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …
                   …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …
                   …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …
                   …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …
                   …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …
                   …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …
                   …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …Description …

                </p>
            </article>
        </div>
    </div>
```

Now i output result i see blank/empty below of image:

[image]

How do can i fix this problem?

Demo : http://jsfiddle.net/mth4aLx3/

Answer (score 5):

In your css: **[FORKED JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ryeballar/6x5265qt/2/)**

Change

```
.news-thumbs{
  margin: 10px;
}
```

to

```
.news-thumbs{
  margin: 0 10px 0 10px;
  padding-bottom: 0;
}
```

Comment: if change `margin: 0 10px 0 10px;`(margin-top:0) your code not work. demo : http://jsfiddle.net/mth4aLx3/2/